# RADIUS VLAN Assignment with Cisco ISE

Tags: cisco, vlan, radius, cisco-ise

I am trying to install Cisco ISE 2.1 to be used as a RADIUS server with 802.1x on my switches. I want to dynamically assign a VLAN based to a user who connects on the switch port.

The problem is that, although my end client is authenticated and authorized by ISE, the VLAN id never gets received on the switch from ISE.

On ISE, I see my end user being authenticated with the correct policy, and authorized with the policy I created.

[image: DOT1X config ISE]

As seen on this image, I want to assign VLAN 56. However, my port does not get this information and stays in the hardcoded VLAN.

What could be the issue here?

Could it be that RADIUS options 064,065,081 are not forwarded from the ISE to the switch? I have a firewall between them.

Here is the configuration for dot1x on my switch :

```
aaa new-model
aaa group server tacacs+ ServISE
 server-private X.X.X.X key XXXXX
aaa authentication login default local
aaa authentication login CON none
aaa authentication login VTY group ServISE local
aaa authentication dot1x default group radius local
aaa authorization console
aaa authorization exec CON none
aaa authorization exec VTY group ServISE local if-authenticated
aaa authorization network default group radius

radius-server host X.X.X.X auth-port 1645 acct-port 1646 key 7 XXXX


interface FastEthernet0/10
 switchport access vlan 88
 switchport mode access
 switchport voice vlan 372
 authentication event fail action next-method
 authentication event server dead action authorize vlan 56
 authentication event server alive action reinitialize
 authentication host-mode multi-auth
 authentication port-control auto
 authentication violation restrict
 dot1x pae authenticator
 spanning-tree portfast
```

And here is an output when the end user is authenticated through dot1x :

```
 Dot1x Info for FastEthernet0/10
 -----------------------------------
 PAE                       = AUTHENTICATOR
 PortControl               = AUTO
 ControlDirection          = Both
 HostMode                  = MULTI_AUTH
 QuietPeriod               = 60
 ServerTimeout             = 0
 SuppTimeout               = 30
 ReAuthMax                 = 2
 MaxReq                    = 2
 TxPeriod                  = 30

 Dot1x Authenticator Client List
 -------------------------------
 Supplicant                = 34e6.d735.483c
 Session ID                = 84A8A830000000254EE2CCAB
     Auth SM State         = AUTHENTICATED
     Auth BEND SM State    = IDLE
 Port Status               = AUTHORIZED
```

Here is the output of a debug dot1x all

```
275: Jun 16 18:30:40.370: dot1x-ev(Fa0/10): dot1x_exec_reauth_interface: Reauthenticating Authenticator instances
276: Jun 16 18:30:40.370: dot1x-sm(Fa0/10): Posting REAUTHENTICATE on Client 0xF5000034
277: Jun 16 18:30:40.370:     dot1x_auth Fa0/10: during state auth_authenticated, got event 17(reAuthenticate)
278: Jun 16 18:30:40.370: @@@ dot1x_auth Fa0/10: auth_authenticated -> auth_restart
279: Jun 16 18:30:40.370: dot1x-sm(Fa0/10): 0xF5000034:auth_authenticated_exit called
280  Jun 16 18:30:40.370: dot1x-sm(Fa0/10): 0xF5000034:auth_restart_enter called
281: Jun 16 18:30:40.370: dot1x-ev(Fa0/10): Sending create new context event to EAP for 0xF5000034 (34e6.d735.483c)
282: Jun 16 18:30:40.370: dot1x-sm(Fa0/10): 0xF5000034:auth_authenticated_restart_action called
283: Jun 16 18:30:40.370: dot1x-sm(Fa0/10): Posting !EAP_RESTART on Client 0xF5000034
284: Jun 16 18:30:40.370:     dot1x_auth Fa0/10: during state auth_restart, got event 6(no_eapRestart)
285: Jun 16 18:30:40.370: @@@ dot1x_auth Fa0/10: auth_restart -> auth_connecting
286: Jun 16 18:30:40.370: dot1x-sm(Fa0/10): 0xF5000034:auth_connecting_enter called
287: Jun 16 18:30:40.370: dot1x-sm(Fa0/10): 0xF5000034:auth_restart_connecting_action called
288: Jun 16 18:30:40.370: dot1x-sm(Fa0/10): Posting RX_REQ on Client 0xF5000034
289: Jun 16 18:30:40.370:     dot1x_auth Fa0/10: during state auth_connecting, got event 10(eapReq_no_reAuthMax)
290: Jun 16 18:30:40.370: @@@ dot1x_auth Fa0/10: auth_connecting -> auth_authenticating
291: Jun 16 18:30:40.370: dot1x-sm(Fa0/10): 0xF5000034:auth_authenticating_enter called
292: Jun 16 18:30:40.370: dot1x-sm(Fa0/10): 0xF5000034:auth_connecting_authenticating_action called
293: Jun 16 18:30:40.370: dot1x-sm(Fa0/10): Posting AUTH_START for 0xF5000034
294: Jun 16 18:30:40.370:     dot1x_auth_bend Fa0/10: during state auth_bend_idle, got event 4(eapReq_authStart)
295: Jun 16 18:30:40.370: @@@ dot1x_auth_bend Fa0/10: auth_bend_idle -> auth_bend_request
296: Jun 16 18:30:40.370: dot1x-sm(Fa0/10): 0xF5000034:auth_bend_request_enter called
297: Jun 16 18:30:40.370: dot1x-packet(Fa0/10): EAP code: 0x1  id: 0x4E length: 0x0005 type: 0x1  data:
298: Jun 16 18:30:40.370: dot1x-ev(Fa0/10): Sending EAPOL packet to 34e6.d735.483c
299: Jun 16 18:30:40.370: dot1x-ev(Fa0/10): Role determination not required
300: Jun 16 18:30:40.370: dot1x-registry:registry:dot1x_ether_macaddr called
301: Jun 16 18:30:40.370: dot1x-ev(Fa0/10): Sending out EAPOL packet
302: Jun 16 18:30:40.370: EAPOL pak dump Tx
303: Jun 16 18:30:40.370: EAPOL Version: 0x2  type: 0x0  length: 0x0005
304: Jun 16 18:30:40.370: EAP code: 0x1  id: 0x4E length: 0x0005 type: 0x1
305: Jun 16 18:30:40.370: dot1x-packet(Fa0/10): EAPOL packet sent to client 0xF5000034 (34e6.d735.483c)
306: Jun 16 18:30:40.370: dot1x-sm(Fa0/10): 0xF5000034:auth_bend_idle_request_action called
307: Jun 16 18:30:40.378: dot1x-ev(Fa0/10): Role determination not required
308: Jun 16 18:30:40.378: dot1x-packet(Fa0/10): Queuing an EAPOL pkt on Authenticator Q
309: Jun 16 18:30:40.378: dot1x-ev:Enqueued the eapol packet to the global authenticator queue
310: Jun 16 18:30:40.378: EAPOL pak dump rx
311: Jun 16 18:30:40.378: EAPOL Version: 0x1  type: 0x0  length: 0x0020
312: Jun 16 18:30:40.378: dot1x-ev:dot1x_auth_queue_event: Int Fa0/10 CODE= 2,TYPE= 1,LEN= 32
313: Jun 16 18:30:40.378: dot1x-packet(Fa0/10): Received an EAPOL frame
314: Jun 16 18:30:40.378: dot1x-ev(Fa0/10): Received pkt saddr =34e6.d735.483c , daddr = 0180.c200.0003, pae-ether-type = 888e.0100.0020
315: Jun 16 18:30:40.378: dot1x-packet(Fa0/10): Received an EAP packet
316: Jun 16 18:30:40.378: EAPOL pak dump rx
317: Jun 16 18:30:40.378: EAPOL Version: 0x1  type: 0x0  length: 0x0020
318: Jun 16 18:30:40.378: dot1x-packet(Fa0/10): Received an EAP packet from 34e6.d735.483c
319: Jun 16 18:30:40.378: dot1x-sm(Fa0/10): Posting EAPOL_EAP for 0xF5000034
320: Jun 16 18:30:40.378:     dot1x_auth_bend Fa0/10: during state auth_bend_request, got event 6(eapolEap)
321: Jun 16 18:30:40.378: @@@ dot1x_auth_bend Fa0/10: auth_bend_request -> auth_bend_response
322: Jun 16 18:30:40.378: dot1x-sm(Fa0/10): 0xF5000034:auth_bend_response_enter called
323: Jun 16 18:30:40.378: dot1x-ev(Fa0/10): dot1x_sendRespToServer: Response sent to the server from 0xF5000034 (34e6.d735.483c)
324: Jun 16 18:30:40.378: dot1x-sm(Fa0/10): 0xF5000034:auth_bend_request_response_action called
325: Jun 16 18:30:40.395: dot1x-sm(Fa0/10): Posting EAP_REQ for 0xF5000034
326: Jun 16 18:30:40.395:     dot1x_auth_bend Fa0/10: during state auth_bend_response, got event 7(eapReq)
327: Jun 16 18:30:40.395: @@@ dot1x_auth_bend Fa0/10: auth_bend_response -> auth_bend_request
328: Jun 16 18:30:40.395: dot1x-sm(Fa0/10): 0xF5000034:auth_bend_response_exit called
329: Jun 16 18:30:40.395: dot1x-sm(Fa0/10): 0xF5000034:auth_bend_request_enter called
330: Jun 16 18:30:40.395: dot1x-packet(Fa0/10): EAP code: 0x1  id: 0x2B length: 0x0006 type: 0xD  data:
331: Jun 16 18:30:40.395: dot1x-ev(Fa0/10): Sending EAPOL packet to 34e6.d735.483c
332: Jun 16 18:30:40.395: dot1x-ev(Fa0/10): Role determination not required
333: Jun 16 18:30:40.395: dot1x-registry:registry:dot1x_ether_macaddr called
334: Jun 16 18:30:40.395: dot1x-ev(Fa0/10): Sending out EAPOL packet
335: Jun 16 18:30:40.395: EAPOL pak dump Tx
336: Jun 16 18:30:40.395: EAPOL Version: 0x2  type:0x0  length: 0x0006
337: Jun 16 18:30:40.395: EAP code: 0x1  id: 0x2B length: 0x0006 type: 0xD
338: Jun 16 18:30:40.395: dot1x-packet(Fa0/10): EAPOL packet sent to client 0xF5000034 (34e6.d735.483c)
339: Jun 16 18:30:40.395: dot1x-sm(Fa0/10): 0xF5000034:auth_bend_response_request_action called
340: Jun 16 18:30:40.404: dot1x-ev(Fa0/10): Role determination not required
341: Jun 16 18:30:40.404: dot1x-packet(Fa0/10): Queuing an EAPOL pkt on Authenticator Q
342: Jun 16 18:30:40.404: dot1x-ev:Enqueued the eapol packet to the global authenticator queue
343: Jun 16 18:30:40.404: EAPOL pak dump rx
344: Jun 16 18:30:40.404: EAPOL Version: 0x1  type: 0x0  length: 0x0006
345: Jun 16 18:30:40.404: dot1x-ev:dot1x_auth_queue_event: Int Fa0/10 CODE= 2,TYPE= 3,LEN= 6
```

Here is the output for "debug radius authentication"

```
685: Jun 17 09:06:23.838: RADIUS/ENCODE(000004D5):Orig. component type = DOT1X
686: Jun 17 09:06:23.838: RADIUS(000004D5): Config NAS IP: 0.0.0.0
687: Jun 17 09:06:23.838: RADIUS/ENCODE(000004D5): acct_session_id: 1237
688: Jun 17 09:06:23.838: RADIUS(000004D5): sending
689: Jun 17 09:06:23.838: RADIUS/ENCODE: Best Local IP-Address 1.1.1.1 for Radius-Server X.X.X.X
690: Jun 17 09:06:23.838: RADIUS(000004D5): Send Access-Request to X.X.X.X:1645 id 1645/16, len 236
691: Jun 17 09:06:23.838: RADIUS:  authenticator C8 97 74 7C 01 99 CE 9E - 11 D2 87 96 10 15 A4 43
692: Jun 17 09:06:23.838: RADIUS:  User-Name           [1]   29  "host/MyComputer.testdomain.com"
693: Jun 17 09:06:23.838: RADIUS:  Service-Type        [6]   6   Framed                    [2]
694: Jun 17 09:06:23.838: RADIUS:  Framed-MTU          [12]  6   1500
695: Jun 17 09:06:23.838: RADIUS:  Called-Station-Id   [30]  19  "C8-F9-F9-C9-45-0C"
696: Jun 17 09:06:23.838: RADIUS:  Calling-Station-Id  [31]  19  "34-E6-D7-35-48-3C"
697: Jun 17 09:06:23.838: RADIUS:  EAP-Message         [79]  34
698: Jun 17 09:06:23.838: RADIUS:   02 85 00 20 01 68 6F 73 74 2F 47 52 45 30 34 37 39 34 37 2E  [ host/MyComputer.]
699: Jun 17 09:06:23.838: RADIUS:   69 6E 74 72 61 2E 63 65 61 2E 66 72      [ testdomain.com]
700: Jun 17 09:06:23.838: RADIUS:  Message-Authenticato[80]  18
701: Jun 17 09:06:23.838: RADIUS:   02 09 C8 4B FC 82 96 B9 61 8A 24 F6 81 4A 0B C2[ Ka$J]
702: Jun 17 09:06:23.846: RADIUS:  Vendor, Cisco       [26]  49
703: Jun 17 09:06:23.846: RADIUS:   Cisco AVpair       [1]   43  "audit-session-id=84A8A830000000254EE2CCAB"
704: Jun 17 09:06:23.846: RADIUS:  NAS-Port-Type       [61]  6   Ethernet                  [15]
705: Jun 17 09:06:23.846: RADIUS:  NAS-Port            [5]   6   5    0
706: Jun 17 09:06:23.846: RADIUS:  NAS-Port-Id         [87]  18  "FastEthernet0/10"
707: Jun 17 09:06:23.846: RADIUS:  NAS-IP-Address      [4]   6   1.1.1.1
708: Jun 17 09:06:23.846: RADIUS: Received from id 1645/16 X.X.X.X:1645, Access-Challenge, len 127
709: Jun 17 09:06:23.846: RADIUS:  authenticator 71 6A C0 FC 82 FE 8A 64 - 22 FA 09 EE 44 33 5A ED
710: Jun 17 09:06:23.846: RADIUS:  State               [24]  81
711: Jun 17 09:06:23.846: RADIUS:   33 37 43 50 4D 53 65 73 73 69 6F 6E 49 44 3D 38  [37CPMSessionID=8]
712: Jun 17 09:06:23.855: RADIUS:   34 41 38 41 38 33 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 32 35 34  [4A8A830000000254]
713: Jun 17 09:06:23.855: RADIUS:   45 45 32 43 43 41 42 3B 33 36 53 65 73 73 69 6F  [EE2CCAB;36Sessio]
714: Jun 17 09:06:23.855: RADIUS:   6E 49 44 3D 67 72 65 78 70 33 31 32 61 64 6D 2F  [nID=MyComputer/]
715: Jun 17 09:06:23.855: RADIUS:   32 35 34 38 33 38 36 35 35 2F 31 38 37 35 3B   [ 254838655/1875;]
716: Jun 17 09:06:23.855: RADIUS:  EAP-Message         [79]  8
717: Jun 17 09:06:23.855: RADIUS:   01 44 00 06 0D 20[ D ]
718: Jun 17 09:06:23.855: RADIUS:  Message-Authenticato[80]  18
719: Jun 17 09:06:23.855: RADIUS:   AF 6F 4C 96 0A 75 CE 3D 4B 4C 7D ED E9 A9 94 48          [ oLu=KL}H]
720: Jun 17 09:06:23.855: RADIUS(000004D5): Received from id 1645/16
721: Jun 17 09:06:23.855: RADIUS/DECODE: EAP-Message fragments, 6, total 6 bytes
```

Comment: You can try "debug radius authentication" or "debug dot1x all" on the switch to see what messages it is receiving.

Comment: I did that, and edited my post to add the output above. I don't see anything really strange in the output though.

Comment: I don't either.  How about the radius debug?

Comment: I added it as well. Nothing out of the ordinary stands out... Also I added a snapshot of my config on ISE

Comment: Great data, great question.  +1

Comment: My guess (and it's only a guess) is that ISE isn't sending the right options.  I would have expected to see more in the debug.

Comment: I'm not an ISE expert, but there must be a log or debug option to let you know what it's doing.

Comment: We have a rather similar configuration, which is actually working. I know, stupid idea, but could you please verify that the AuthorizationProfile is actually used by the auth policy matching? Additionally, please check the ISE RADIUS Livelog (Operations tab) and click the small question mark on your session, which will show a lot more information from ISE perspective.

Comment: The AuthProfile I created is indeed used by ISE. Also I checked the "details" section of the RADIUS Livelogs, and it goes all the way to authorization successful. Quick question though: do I have to check the box marked "Service Template" on my Authorization Profile?

Comment: @JeremyG. no, the Service Template box does not need to be checked. At least it is not in our deployment. In the debugs above the RADIUS Access Accept message is missing. Some stupid questions: I guess the VLAN actually exists? What does "sh auth ses int fa 0/10 detail" show? What is the exact switch model and version?

Comment: You haven't posted the RADIUS server configuration, which would be helpful for further diag... ie:
radius server ISEPSN address ipv4 10.10.10.10 key SomeSecretKet timeout 5 The switch provisioning guide below (while older) is still very relevant, especially when it comes to CoA. http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/ise/1.0/user_guide/ise10_sw_cnfg.html#wp1059672 Cheers!

Comment: which IOS version are you using ? may be it is bug and you need update , I have faced same issue with Bocade switch and it is resolved by firmware upgrade

Comment: @Travis : I added the radius server line.

Comment: @Mr.lock : my switch is a 3560 and its version is 12.2(50r)SE. it could be a firmware issue, but the TAC did not think that way. I will try another switch ASAP though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those still interested in this issue, I had to upgrade the IOS to 12.2(55)SE10. Now it's working with the initial configuration.

Comment: I would consider to upgrade to newer IOS version 15.*. Recommended version is marked as Golden image.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you've already done this, but you have to go a step further than just creating the Auth profile. You have to apply that auth profile with an auth policy. To create the auth policy do the following.

Go to Policy / Authorization
Edit – profiles –standard, select your auth profile 
click Done
click Save

Comment: You should edit your answer to explain it.

Comment: @BlackMagix : I applied this Auth profile to an auth policy indeed. Moreover, I did a tcpdump on ISE during the authorization process, and i can see an "ACCESS-ACCEPT" frame sent by ISE with the correct VLAN ID. Therefore I think the issue is more on the switch than on ISE.